# VS Code group-aware sort imports on save for TypeScript 4.7

Tags: visual-studio-code, developer-tools

with 4.7 typescript in VS code can sort imports within "groups". see: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68#_group-aware-organize-imports

I tried it out using `shift`+`opt`+`o`; and it works great! However, I like to sort on save using:

```
//settings.json
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
},
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not sort with any awareness of groups. Any ideas what the difference is? Could the on-save organize not be using 4.7, or is this a different organization method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I was running an out of date version of VS Code.

Menu > Code > Check for Updates then restart fixes the issue for me.

---

**Edit**: Comments suggested that I provide more context and citations.

[VS Code (Visual Studio Code) is an application released in 2015 as an open source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). Since its initial release it has seen [many updates](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases) to introduce new functionality. These updates can be preformed by the user of the application using built in functionality, this process was described in my initial answer as

> Menu > Code > Check for Updates

This is a common shorthand to describe navigating the applications menus [citation needed]. More info on navigation bars can be found in the [wikipedia entry for navigation bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_bar). But to be more descriptive, using mouse or keyboard input select the first menu item "Code" then select "Check for Updates".

IMPORTANT NOTE: the exact menu structure may vary depending on the operating system and version of the application.

"Check for updates" will initiate a process where the application uses the internet to check for updates. This requires an internet connection.

As noted in the question the [1.68 version, aka "May 2022 update"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68); is required for the described functionality. By running the "Check for updates" process the application was able to update to this version.

Furthermore, the original answer indicated that restarting the application was required. VS Code does not offer "restart" functionality; however the same can be achieved by closing and manually reopening the application. For more detailed information see [Rebooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot).

Finally, the reader may find it useful to check the current version of the application. This can be done before or after "Check for updates" is run. To do so use the "About Visual Studio Code" menu option under the "Code" top level menu. The current version will be listed after "Version: " and can be compared to the required version mentioned here (1.68) using [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't take much to make a good answer: just provide a little explanation and context and it'll be OK. Please keep this in mind when asking and answering in the future.

Comment: @music2myear thanks for the feedback. I have updated.